# Join 2 table and group 2 field in linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a very simple SQL

```
SELECT s.shop_code
             ,SUM(im.amt)      sum_amt
             ,s.cell_no#1      shop_cell
       FROM   tb_sn_so_wt_mst  im
             ,tb_cm_shop_inf   s 
       WHERE  im.shop_code   = s.shop_code
GROUP BY s.shop_code, s.cell_no#1)
```

then i try to code linq

```
var listResult = from warrantyMaster in listWarrantyMasters2.Records
                                          join shopInfo in listShopInfos
                                          on warrantyMaster.ShopCode equals shopInfo.ShopCode
```

i don't know group by shop code and cell no and sum atm, any one help me out of this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group by syntax with some examples is explained here [group clause (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384063.aspx) and related links.

Here is the direct translation of your SQL query (of course the field names are just my guess since you didn't provide your classes):

```
var query = from im in listWarrantyMasters2.Records
            join s in listShopInfos
            on im.ShopCode equals s.ShopCode
            group im by new { s.ShopCode, s.CellNo } into g
            select new
            {
                g.Key.ShopCode,
                g.Key.CellNo,
                SumAmt = g.Sum(e => e.Amt)
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
 var results = from warrantyMaster in listWarrantyMasters2.Records
                  from shopInfo in listShopInfos
                       .Where(mapping => mapping.ShopCode == warrantyMaster.ShopCode )
                       .select new 
                       { 
                            ShopCode = warrantyMaster.ShopCode,
                            ATM = listWarrantyMasters2.ATM,
                            ShellNo = shopInfo.ShellNo
                       }
                       .GroupBy(x=> new { x.ShopCode, x.ShellNo })
                       .Select(x=> 
                       new{ 
                             ShopCode = x.Key.ShopCode,
                             ShellNo = x.Key.ShellNo,
                             SumATM = x.Sum(item=>item.ATM)
                       });
```

Comment: IM here is not a field im is shortcut of table tb_sn_so_wt_mst, did you wrong

Comment: Sorry that is my mistake, I have already updated the code above. Please try it again. The idea is how to use group by with sum function. So you can  recheck and replace with your properties correctly